# On iOS 6.1, UISwitch IBOutlet is always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am having some trouble while working with UISwitch on a static `UITableView`.
I have to restore the last state of a certain `UISwitch` when the App loads, but whenever I check the state of the `IBOutlet`, it is nil. I have tried to manually alloc the variable, which was of no help either.

Here is what I am doing:

SettingsController.h

```
//IBOutlet connected correctly
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *switch_displayDetail;
```

SettingsController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (!_switch_displayDetail) {
        NSLog(@"_switch_displayDetail is NIL"); //This is always displayed
    }

    //Switch is default to YES, I am trying to set it to NO
    //This line does nothing...
    [_switch_displayDetail setOn:[dataManager shouldDisplayDetail] animated:YES];
}
```

Everywhere else when I check the state of `_switch_displayDetail` it is nil. I am calling all the super initialization methods.
Did anything change on iOS 6.1?

[EDIT] Using the synthesized variable does not work either.

[EDIT 2] Found the problem to be a bug on Xcode or on iPhone Simulator. After testing on my iPod touch, the initial algorithm worked perfectly.

I am going nuts with this problem...

Comment: check if u are doing `initWithNibName` and not just `init` on the SettingsController

Comment: Also check you're spelling the nib name correctly.

Comment: try self.switch_displayDetail instead of _switch_displayDetail

Comment: Unlink/relink the outlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers, but after almost giving up, I tested my App on my iPod touch and it worked perfectly. This looks like a bug on the iPhone Simulator or, much probably a bug on Xcode (nothing new here). After reseting all settings and data on the iPhone Simulator menu, it worked there too.

So, before going crazy, **test your App on a real device**.

Comment: Resetting settings and data in the Simulator did it for me too. Also, I experienced this on iOS 6.0 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know first hand how frustrating those *Twilight zone* issues can be. There's obviously too little information to diagnose but I thought I'd share how I'd approach the debugging.

1. Override the setter for switch_displayDetail, in there, log the value but also `self`
2. Then in `viewWillAppear`, log the same thing

I have a feeling we're not talking about the same instance here. If I'm right, the setter will display a value, but not `viewWillAppear`. If I'm wrong, then both will be nil and in that case either you're not calling the right `init` method, or your linkage isn't right in IB.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Thank you. I thought of the same thing. I am gonna try this and post the results here.

Answer (score -1):

First :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *switch_displayDetail; // should be a weak property
```

And then have you @synthesized your property ?

Comment: On iOS 6.0 properties do not need to to be synthesized